# Regex to extract IBAN ignoring colon

Tags: python, regex, iban

**I want to improve regex that works with the following string:**

```
Uw BTW nummer NL80

IBAN NL 11abna0317164300asdfasf234

(SPACE)iBAN NL21ABNA0417134300 22

Iban: NL 29 ABNA 401422366f sdf

IBAN :NL 39 ABNA 0822416395s
```

And created regex failed to extract IBAN Mask on the 4th line. I want to improve it by allowing zero or one occurrence of colon (`:`) after IBAN and zero or one space after colon character.

```
(?<=[Ii][Bb][Aa][Nn]\s).*[Nn][Ll]\s?\d{2}\s?[a-zA-Z]{4}[0 ]\s?\d{9,10})
```

**Regex demo:**

https://regex101.com/r/zGDXa2/7

Much appreciated!

Comment: Try replacing `\s` with `[\s:]`, see https://regex101.com/r/zGDXa2/8

Comment: Is `NL 29 ABNA 401422366f` IBAN correct? It has an `f` at the end.

Comment: U already asked this question, people already helped you, u didn't reply and created new one.

Comment: It was 2 different approaches how to ignor :

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://regex101.com/r/zGDXa2/10

Comment: I have answered your question in the duplicate! Have a look ;-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Much appreciated, it work! have to only adjust splitting colon on the fifth line.

Comment: @Asunez Thanks, yes it was appended just for testing )

Comment: @Dmitrii pardon, sir i am a rookie to local SO interface will be more accurate from now on

Comment: @Asunez Much appreciated, it works in case one wants to split string including IBAN as well.

Comment: @Allan Much appreciated!